# SharePoint 2010 CQWP not rendering calendar list description field

Tags: sharepoint-2010, cqwp

We have a SP2010 site that we are making extensive use of the CQWP (Content Query Web Part) on. When I point the CQWP at a specific list it displays description value fine. The problem is when I point it at a hierarchy of SPWebs and configure it to rollup all items of type Calendar. When I do this all data comes through fine except for Description, which is very odd. I tried using internal field name too it doesn't seem to make any difference.

So my question is how do I get CQWP to render description field from multiple calendar lists?

Comment: see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12128/sharepoint-2010-cqwp-not-rendering-calendar-list-description-field

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by changing the DataMappings, and DataMappingViewFields. The values in these fields are very sensitive and a space or semi-colon in the wrong place  will break it. I've posted what worked below, hopefully this will save someone else two days of misery!

```
<property name="DataMappings" type="string">Title:{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Title,Text;|LinkUrl:|Description:{9da97a8a-1da5-4a77-98d3-4bc10456e700},Comments,Note;|ImageUrl:{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl,Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},PublishingRollupImage,Image;|EndDate:{2684f9f2-54be-429f-ba06-76754fc056bf},EndDate,DateTime;|EventDate:{64cd368d-2f95-4bfc-a1f9-8d4324ecb007},StartDate,DateTime;|</property>


<property name="DataMappingViewFields" type="string">{b9e6f3ae-5632-4b13-b636-9d1a2bd67120},Computed;{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac},Image;{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247},Text;{9da97a8a-1da5-4a77-98d3-4bc10456e700},Note;{64cd368d-2f95-4bfc-a1f9-8d4324ecb007},DateTime;{2684f9f2-54be-429f-ba06-76754fc056bf},DateTime;</property>
```